# Unable to locate HardwareRenderer class in the master branch of Android Open Source Code

Tags: android

I could find reference to HardwareRenderer in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/07301cf/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java but the lastest master branch, under DevelopmentSettings.java, there is no reference.

Please help me with the alternative location and the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have noticed carefully in `DevelopmentSettings.java`, the imported package for **HardwareRenderer** is `import android.view.HardwareRenderer;` so find `HardwareRenderer.java` in **view**

Here is the location of `HardwareRenderer.java` class under **view** in Android Open Source:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e40462e11d27eb859b829b112cecb8c6f0d7afb/core/java/android/view/HardwareRenderer.java

Comment: I am unable to find import android.view.HardwareRenderer in DevelopmentSettings.java. Can you please help me to locate the branch information in the source code as the repo sync has been done by someone else and I am not sure which branch of aosc is used. I will share the same in my next reply to explore further.

Comment: @DipankarMaitra can't you see `android.view.HardwareRenderer` in imported packages of `DevelopmentSettings.java` at this link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/07301cf/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java

Comment: Also here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/development/DevelopmentSettings.java, I am not able to see import android.view.HardwareRenderer. Instead  import android.view.ThreadedRenderer